# How does Stack Overflow generate its SEO-friendly URLs?

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, seo, friendly-url, slug

What is a good complete [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) or some other process that would take the title:

> How do you change a title to be part of the URL like Stack Overflow?

and turn it into

```
how-do-you-change-a-title-to-be-part-of-the-url-like-stack-overflow
```

that is used in the SEO-friendly URLs on Stack Overflow?

The development environment I am using is [Ruby on Rails](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails), but if there are some other platform-specific solutions (.NET, PHP, [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29)), I would love to see those too.

I am sure I (or another reader) will come across the same problem on a different platform down the line.

I am using custom routes, and I mainly want to know how to alter the string to all special characters are removed, it's all lowercase, and all whitespace is replaced.

Comment: What about funny characters? What are you going to do about those? Umlauts? Punctuation? These need to be considered. Basically, I would use a white-list approach, as opposed to the black-list approaches above: Describe which characters you will allow, which characters you will convert (to what?) and then change the rest to something meaningfull (""). I doubt you can do this in one regex... Why not just loop through the characters?

Comment: Should be migrated to [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com); as the question and answer both specifically deal with SO implementation, and the accepted answer is from @JeffAtwood.

Comment: @casperOne Do you think Jeff is not allowed some non-meta reputation? The question is about "how can one do something like this", not specifically "how is this done here".

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: It's not about Jeff getting some non-meta reputation (how much reputation he has is really not my concern); the question body *specifically referenced StackOverflow's implementation* hence the rationale for it being on meta.

Answer (score 322, accepted):

Here's how we do it. Note that there are probably more edge conditions than you realize at first glance.

This is the second version, unrolled for 5x more performance (and yes, I benchmarked it). I figured I'd optimize it because this function can be called hundreds of times per page.

```
/// <summary>
/// Produces optional, URL-friendly version of a title, "like-this-one". 
/// hand-tuned for speed, reflects performance refactoring contributed
/// by John Gietzen (user otac0n) 
/// </summary>
public static string URLFriendly(string title)
{
    if (title == null) return "";

    const int maxlen = 80;
    int len = title.Length;
    bool prevdash = false;
    var sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    char c;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        c = title[i];
        if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9'))
        {
            sb.Append(c);
            prevdash = false;
        }
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        {
            // tricky way to convert to lowercase
            sb.Append((char)(c | 32));
            prevdash = false;
        }
        else if (c == ' ' || c == ',' || c == '.' || c == '/' || 
            c == '\\' || c == '-' || c == '_' || c == '=')
        {
            if (!prevdash && sb.Length > 0)
            {
                sb.Append('-');
                prevdash = true;
            }
        }
        else if ((int)c >= 128)
        {
            int prevlen = sb.Length;
            sb.Append(RemapInternationalCharToAscii(c));
            if (prevlen != sb.Length) prevdash = false;
        }
        if (i == maxlen) break;
    }

    if (prevdash)
        return sb.ToString().Substring(0, sb.Length - 1);
    else
        return sb.ToString();
}
```

To see the previous version of the code this replaced (but is functionally equivalent to, and 5x faster), view revision history of this post (click the date link).

Also, the `RemapInternationalCharToAscii` method source code can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7696).

Answer (score 37):

Here is my version of Jeff's code. I've made the following changes:

- The hyphens were appended in such a way that one could be added, and then need removing as it was the last character in the string. That is, we never want “my-slug-”. This means an extra string allocation to remove it on this edge case. I’ve worked around this by delay-hyphening. If you compare my code to Jeff’s the logic for this is easy to follow.
- His approach is purely lookup based and missed a lot of characters I found in examples while researching on Stack Overflow. To counter this, I first peform a normalisation pass (AKA collation mentioned in Meta Stack Overflow question *[Non US-ASCII characters dropped from full (profile) URL](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/non-us-ascii-characters-dropped-from-full-profile-url/7696#7696)*), and then ignore any characters outside the acceptable ranges. This works most of the time...
- ... For when it doesn’t I’ve also had to add a lookup table. As mentioned above, some characters don’t map to a low ASCII value when normalised. Rather than drop these I’ve got a manual list of exceptions that is doubtless full of holes, but it is better than nothing. The normalisation code was inspired by Jon Hanna’s great post in Stack Overflow question *[How can I remove accents on a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769457)*.
- The case conversion is now also optional.

  ```
  public static class Slug
  {
      public static string Create(bool toLower, params string[] values)
      {
          return Create(toLower, String.Join("-", values));
      }

      /// <summary>
      /// Creates a slug.
      /// References:
      /// http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr15/tr15-34.html
      /// https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/non-us-ascii-characters-dropped-from-full-profile-url/7696#7696
      /// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-do-you-include-a-webpage-title-as-part-of-a-webpage-url/25486#25486
      /// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769457/how-can-i-remove-accents-on-a-string
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="toLower"></param>
      /// <param name="normalised"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public static string Create(bool toLower, string value)
      {
          if (value == null)
              return "";

          var normalised = value.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKD);

          const int maxlen = 80;
          int len = normalised.Length;
          bool prevDash = false;
          var sb = new StringBuilder(len);
          char c;

          for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
          {
              c = normalised[i];
              if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9'))
              {
                  if (prevDash)
                  {
                      sb.Append('-');
                      prevDash = false;
                  }
                  sb.Append(c);
              }
              else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
              {
                  if (prevDash)
                  {
                      sb.Append('-');
                      prevDash = false;
                  }
                  // Tricky way to convert to lowercase
                  if (toLower)
                      sb.Append((char)(c | 32));
                  else
                      sb.Append(c);
              }
              else if (c == ' ' || c == ',' || c == '.' || c == '/' || c == '\\' || c == '-' || c == '_' || c == '=')
              {
                  if (!prevDash && sb.Length > 0)
                  {
                      prevDash = true;
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                  string swap = ConvertEdgeCases(c, toLower);

                  if (swap != null)
                  {
                      if (prevDash)
                      {
                          sb.Append('-');
                          prevDash = false;
                      }
                      sb.Append(swap);
                  }
              }

              if (sb.Length == maxlen)
                  break;
          }
          return sb.ToString();
      }

      static string ConvertEdgeCases(char c, bool toLower)
      {
          string swap = null;
          switch (c)
          {
              case 'ı':
                  swap = "i";
                  break;
              case 'ł':
                  swap = "l";
                  break;
              case 'Ł':
                  swap = toLower ? "l" : "L";
                  break;
              case 'đ':
                  swap = "d";
                  break;
              case 'ß':
                  swap = "ss";
                  break;
              case 'ø':
                  swap = "o";
                  break;
              case 'Þ':
                  swap = "th";
                  break;
          }
          return swap;
      }
  }
  ```

For more details, the unit tests, and an explanation of why [Facebook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook)'s [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) scheme is a little smarter than Stack Overflows, I've got an [expanded version of this on my blog](http://www.danharman.net/2011/07/18/seo-slugification-in-dotnet-aka-unicode-to-ascii-aka-diacritic-stripping/).

Answer (score 16):

You will want to setup a custom route to point the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) to the controller that will handle it. Since you are using Ruby on Rails, here is an [introduction](http://manuals.rubyonrails.com/read/chapter/65) in using their routing engine.

In Ruby, you will need a regular expression like you already know and here is the regular expression to use:

```
def permalink_for(str)
    str.gsub(/[^\w\/]|[!\(\)\.]+/, ' ').strip.downcase.gsub(/\ +/, '-')
end
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also use this [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) function for in-form generation of the slug's (this one is based on/copied from [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29)):

```
function makeSlug(urlString, filter) {
    // Changes, e.g., "Petty theft" to "petty_theft".
    // Remove all these words from the string before URLifying

    if(filter) {
        removelist = ["a", "an", "as", "at", "before", "but", "by", "for", "from",
        "is", "in", "into", "like", "of", "off", "on", "onto", "per",
        "since", "than", "the", "this", "that", "to", "up", "via", "het", "de", "een", "en",
        "with"];
    }
    else {
        removelist = [];
    }
    s = urlString;
    r = new RegExp('\\b(' + removelist.join('|') + ')\\b', 'gi');
    s = s.replace(r, '');
    s = s.replace(/[^-\w\s]/g, ''); // Remove unneeded characters
    s = s.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); // Trim leading/trailing spaces
    s = s.replace(/[-\s]+/g, '-'); // Convert spaces to hyphens
    s = s.toLowerCase(); // Convert to lowercase
    return s; // Trim to first num_chars characters
}
```

Answer (score 8):

For good measure, here's the PHP function in WordPress that does it... I'd think that WordPress is one of the more popular platforms that uses fancy links.

```
    function sanitize_title_with_dashes($title) {
            $title = strip_tags($title);
            // Preserve escaped octets.
            $title = preg_replace('|%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])|', '---$1---', $title);
            // Remove percent signs that are not part of an octet.
            $title = str_replace('%', '', $title);
            // Restore octets.
            $title = preg_replace('|---([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])---|', '%$1', $title);
            $title = remove_accents($title);
            if (seems_utf8($title)) {
                    if (function_exists('mb_strtolower')) {
                            $title = mb_strtolower($title, 'UTF-8');
                    }
                    $title = utf8_uri_encode($title, 200);
            }
            $title = strtolower($title);
            $title = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $title); // kill entities
            $title = preg_replace('/[^%a-z0-9 _-]/', '', $title);
            $title = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $title);
            $title = preg_replace('|-+|', '-', $title);
            $title = trim($title, '-');
            return $title;
    }
```

This function as well as some of the supporting functions can be found in wp-includes/formatting.php.

Comment: This is not full answer. You are missing functions like : `remove_accents`,`seems_utf8`...

Comment: to complete @The How-To Geek answer you still can `git clone git://core.git.wordpress.org/` and find the `wp-includes/formatting.php` file into

Answer (score 5):

I am not familiar with Ruby on Rails, but the following is (untested) PHP code. You can probably translate this very quickly to Ruby on Rails if you find it useful.

```
$sURL = "This is a title to convert to URL-format. It has 1 number in it!";
// To lower-case
$sURL = strtolower($sURL);

// Replace all non-word characters with spaces
$sURL = preg_replace("/\W+/", " ", $sURL);

// Remove trailing spaces (so we won't end with a separator)
$sURL = trim($sURL);

// Replace spaces with separators (hyphens)
$sURL = str_replace(" ", "-", $sURL);

echo $sURL;
// outputs: this-is-a-title-to-convert-to-url-format-it-has-1-number-in-it
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Rails edge, you can rely on [Inflector.parametrize](http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector.rb#L244) - here's the example from the documentation:

```
  class Person
    def to_param
      "#{id}-#{name.parameterize}"
    end
  end

  @person = Person.find(1)
  # => #<Person id: 1, name: "Donald E. Knuth">

  <%= link_to(@person.name, person_path(@person)) %>
  # => <a href="/person/1-donald-e-knuth">Donald E. Knuth</a>
```

Also if you need to handle more exotic characters such as accents (éphémère) in previous version of Rails, you can use a mixture of [PermalinkFu](http://github.com/technoweenie/permalink_fu/tree/master) and [DiacriticsFu](http://github.com/thbar/diacritics_fu/tree/master):

```
DiacriticsFu::escape("éphémère")
=> "ephemere"

DiacriticsFu::escape("räksmörgås")
=> "raksmorgas"
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't much about Ruby or Rails, but in Perl, this is what I would do:

```
my $title = "How do you change a title to be part of the url like Stackoverflow?";

my $url = lc $title;   # Change to lower case and copy to URL.
$url =~ s/^\s+//g;     # Remove leading spaces.
$url =~ s/\s+$//g;     # Remove trailing spaces.
$url =~ s/\s+/\-/g;    # Change one or more spaces to single hyphen.
$url =~ s/[^\w\-]//g;  # Remove any non-word characters.

print "$title\n$url\n";
```

I just did a quick test and it seems to work.  Hopefully this is relatively easy to translate to Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

T-SQL implementation, adapted from [dbo.UrlEncode](http://www.sqljunkies.com/WebLog/peter_debetta/archive/2007/03/09/28987.aspx):

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Slug(@string varchar(1024))
RETURNS varchar(3072)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @count int, @c char(1), @i int, @slug varchar(3072)

    SET @string = replace(lower(ltrim(rtrim(@string))),' ','-')

    SET @count = Len(@string)
    SET @i = 1
    SET @slug = ''

    WHILE (@i <= @count)
    BEGIN
        SET @c = substring(@string, @i, 1)

        IF @c LIKE '[a-z0-9--]'
            SET @slug = @slug + @c

        SET @i = @i +1
    END

    RETURN @slug
END
```

Answer (score 4):

I know it's very old question but since most of the browsers now **support unicode urls** I found a great solution in **XRegex** that converts everything except letters (in all languages to '-').

That can be done in several programming languages.

The pattern is `\\p{^L}+` and then you just need to use it to replace all non letters to '-'.

Working example in node.js with [xregex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xregexp) module.

```
var text = 'This ! can @ have # several $ letters % from different languages such as עברית or Español';

var slugRegEx = XRegExp('((?!\\d)\\p{^L})+', 'g');

var slug = XRegExp.replace(text, slugRegEx, '-').toLowerCase();

console.log(slug) ==> "this-can-have-several-letters-from-different-languages-such-as-עברית-or-español"
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your model class has a title attribute, you can simply override the to_param method within the model, like this:

```
def to_param
  title.downcase.gsub(/ /, '-')
end
```

[This Railscast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url) has all the details. You can also ensure that the title only contains valid characters using this:

```
validates_format_of :title, :with => /^[a-z0-9-]+$/,
                    :message => 'can only contain letters, numbers and hyphens'
```

Answer (score 2):

Brian's code, in Ruby:

```
title.downcase.strip.gsub(/\ /, '-').gsub(/[^\w\-]/, '')
```

`downcase` turns the string to lowercase, `strip` removes leading and trailing whitespace, the first `gsub` call *g*lobally *sub*stitutes spaces with dashes, and the second removes everything that isn't a letter or a dash.

Answer (score 2):

There is a small Ruby on Rails plugin called [PermalinkFu](http://svn.techno-weenie.net/projects/plugins/permalink_fu/), that does this. The [escape method](http://svn.techno-weenie.net/projects/plugins/permalink_fu/lib/permalink_fu.rb) does the transformation into a string that is suitable for a [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator). Have a look at the code; that method is quite simple.

To remove non-[ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters it uses the iconv lib to translate to 'ascii//ignore//translit' from 'utf-8'. Spaces are then turned into dashes, everything is downcased, etc.

Comment: While this works perfectly, I somehow feel it isn't very efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following helper method. It can convert the Unicode characters.

```
public static string ConvertTextToSlug(string s)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    bool wasHyphen = true;

    foreach (char c in s)
    {
        if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
        {
            sb.Append(char.ToLower(c));
            wasHyphen = false;
        }
        else
            if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c) && !wasHyphen)
            {
                sb.Append('-');
                wasHyphen = true;
            }
    }

    // Avoid trailing hyphens
    if (wasHyphen && sb.Length > 0)
        sb.Length--;

    return sb.ToString().Replace("--","-");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [stackoverflow solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-does-stack-overflow-generate-its-seo-friendly-urls/25486#25486) is great, but modern browser (excluding IE, as usual) now handle nicely utf8 encoding:

[image]

So I upgraded the proposed solution:

```
public static string ToFriendlyUrl(string title, bool useUTF8Encoding = false)
{
    ...

        else if (c >= 128)
        {
            int prevlen = sb.Length;
            if (useUTF8Encoding )
            {
                sb.Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(c.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),Encoding.UTF8));
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(RemapInternationalCharToAscii(c));
            }
    ...
}
```

[Full Code on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/cANXF8eV)

Edit: [Here's the code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7696/245495) for `RemapInternationalCharToAscii` method (that's missing in the pastebin).

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name), Mozilla 1.4, Netscape 7.1, Opera 7.11 were among the first applications to support IDNA. A browser plugin is available for Internet Explorer 6 to provide IDN support. Internet Explorer 7.0 and Windows Vista's URL APIs provide native support for IDN. Sounds like removing UTF-8 characters is a waste of time. Long live UTF-8!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's my (slower, but fun to write) version of Jeff's code:

```
public static string URLFriendly(string title)
{
    char? prevRead = null,
        prevWritten = null;

    var seq = 
        from c in title
        let norm = RemapInternationalCharToAscii(char.ToLowerInvariant(c).ToString())[0]
        let keep = char.IsLetterOrDigit(norm)
        where prevRead.HasValue || keep
        let replaced = keep ? norm
            :  prevWritten != '-' ? '-'
            :  (char?)null
        where replaced != null
        let s = replaced + (prevRead == null ? ""
            : norm == '#' && "cf".Contains(prevRead.Value) ? "sharp"
            : norm == '+' ? "plus"
            : "")
        let _ = prevRead = norm
        from written in s
        let __ = prevWritten = written
        select written;

    const int maxlen = 80;  
    return string.Concat(seq.Take(maxlen)).TrimEnd('-');
}

public static string RemapInternationalCharToAscii(string text)
{
    var seq = text.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD)
        .Where(c => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark);

    return string.Concat(seq).Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormC);
}
```

My test string:

`"  I love C#, F#, C++, and... Crème brûlée!!! They see me codin'... they hatin'... tryin' to catch me codin' dirty... "`

Answer (score 1):

I liked the way this is done without using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), so I ported it to PHP. I just added a function called `is_between` to check characters:

```
function is_between($val, $min, $max)
{
    $val = (int) $val; $min = (int) $min; $max = (int) $max;

    return ($val >= $min && $val <= $max);
}

function international_char_to_ascii($char)
{
    if (mb_strpos('àåáâäãåa', $char) !== false)
    {
        return 'a';
    }

    if (mb_strpos('èéêëe', $char) !== false)
    {
        return 'e';
    }

    if (mb_strpos('ìíîïi', $char) !== false)
    {
        return 'i';
    }

    if (mb_strpos('òóôõö', $char) !== false)
    {
        return 'o';
    }

    if (mb_strpos('ùúûüuu', $char) !== false)
    {
        return 'u';
    }

    if (mb_strpos('çccc', $char) !== false)
    {
        return 'c';
    }

    if (mb_strpos('zzž', $char) !== false)
    {
        return 'z';
    }

    if (mb_strpos('ssšs', $char) !== false)
    {
        return 's';
    }

    if (mb_strpos('ñn', $char) !== false)
    {
        return 'n';
    }

    if (mb_strpos('ýÿ', $char) !== false)
    {
        return 'y';
    }

    if (mb_strpos('gg', $char) !== false)
    {
        return 'g';
    }

    if (mb_strpos('r', $char) !== false)
    {
        return 'r';
    }

    if (mb_strpos('l', $char) !== false)
    {
        return 'l';
    }

    if (mb_strpos('d', $char) !== false)
    {
        return 'd';
    }

    if (mb_strpos('ß', $char) !== false)
    {
        return 'ss';
    }

    if (mb_strpos('Þ', $char) !== false)
    {
        return 'th';
    }

    if (mb_strpos('h', $char) !== false)
    {
        return 'h';
    }

    if (mb_strpos('j', $char) !== false)
    {
        return 'j';
    }
    return '';
}

function url_friendly_title($url_title)
{
    if (empty($url_title))
    {
        return '';
    }

    $url_title = mb_strtolower($url_title);

    $url_title_max_length   = 80;
    $url_title_length       = mb_strlen($url_title);
    $url_title_friendly     = '';
    $url_title_dash_added   = false;
    $url_title_char = '';

    for ($i = 0; $i < $url_title_length; $i++)
    {
        $url_title_char     = mb_substr($url_title, $i, 1);

        if (strlen($url_title_char) == 2)
        {
            $url_title_ascii    = ord($url_title_char[0]) * 256 + ord($url_title_char[1]) . "\r\n";
        }
        else
        {
            $url_title_ascii    = ord($url_title_char);
        }

        if (is_between($url_title_ascii, 97, 122) || is_between($url_title_ascii, 48, 57))
        {
            $url_title_friendly .= $url_title_char;

            $url_title_dash_added = false;
        }
        elseif(is_between($url_title_ascii, 65, 90))
        {
            $url_title_friendly .= chr(($url_title_ascii | 32));

            $url_title_dash_added = false;
        }
        elseif($url_title_ascii == 32 || $url_title_ascii == 44 || $url_title_ascii == 46 || $url_title_ascii == 47 || $url_title_ascii == 92 || $url_title_ascii == 45 || $url_title_ascii == 47 || $url_title_ascii == 95 || $url_title_ascii == 61)
        {
            if (!$url_title_dash_added && mb_strlen($url_title_friendly) > 0)
            {
                $url_title_friendly .= chr(45);

                $url_title_dash_added = true;
            }
        }
        else if ($url_title_ascii >= 128)
        {
            $url_title_previous_length = mb_strlen($url_title_friendly);

            $url_title_friendly .= international_char_to_ascii($url_title_char);

            if ($url_title_previous_length != mb_strlen($url_title_friendly))
            {
                $url_title_dash_added = false;
            }
        }

        if ($i == $url_title_max_length)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($url_title_dash_added)
    {
        return mb_substr($url_title_friendly, 0, -1);
    }
    else
    {
        return $url_title_friendly;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now all Browser handle nicely utf8 encoding, so you can use [WebUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method , its like [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h10z5byc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) used by @giamin but its work outside of a web application.

Answer (score 1):

I ported the code to TypeScript. It can easily be adapted to JavaScript.

I am adding a `.contains` method to the `String` prototype, if you're targeting the latest browsers or ES6 you can use `.includes` instead.

```
if (!String.prototype.contains) {
    String.prototype.contains = function (check) {
        return this.indexOf(check, 0) !== -1;
    };
}

declare interface String {
    contains(check: string): boolean;
}

export function MakeUrlFriendly(title: string) {
            if (title == null || title == '')
                return '';

            const maxlen = 80;
            let len = title.length;
            let prevdash = false;
            let result = '';
            let c: string;
            let cc: number;
            let remapInternationalCharToAscii = function (c: string) {
                let s = c.toLowerCase();
                if ("àåáâäãåą".contains(s)) {
                    return "a";
                }
                else if ("èéêëę".contains(s)) {
                    return "e";
                }
                else if ("ìíîïı".contains(s)) {
                    return "i";
                }
                else if ("òóôõöøőð".contains(s)) {
                    return "o";
                }
                else if ("ùúûüŭů".contains(s)) {
                    return "u";
                }
                else if ("çćčĉ".contains(s)) {
                    return "c";
                }
                else if ("żźž".contains(s)) {
                    return "z";
                }
                else if ("śşšŝ".contains(s)) {
                    return "s";
                }
                else if ("ñń".contains(s)) {
                    return "n";
                }
                else if ("ýÿ".contains(s)) {
                    return "y";
                }
                else if ("ğĝ".contains(s)) {
                    return "g";
                }
                else if (c == 'ř') {
                    return "r";
                }
                else if (c == 'ł') {
                    return "l";
                }
                else if (c == 'đ') {
                    return "d";
                }
                else if (c == 'ß') {
                    return "ss";
                }
                else if (c == 'Þ') {
                    return "th";
                }
                else if (c == 'ĥ') {
                    return "h";
                }
                else if (c == 'ĵ') {
                    return "j";
                }
                else {
                    return "";
                }
            };

            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                c = title[i];
                cc = c.charCodeAt(0);

                if ((cc >= 97 /* a */ && cc <= 122 /* z */) || (cc >= 48 /* 0 */ && cc <= 57 /* 9 */)) {
                    result += c;
                    prevdash = false;
                }
                else if ((cc >= 65 && cc <= 90 /* A - Z */)) {
                    result += c.toLowerCase();
                    prevdash = false;
                }
                else if (c == ' ' || c == ',' || c == '.' || c == '/' || c == '\\' || c == '-' || c == '_' || c == '=') {
                    if (!prevdash && result.length > 0) {
                        result += '-';
                        prevdash = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (cc >= 128) {
                    let prevlen = result.length;
                    result += remapInternationalCharToAscii(c);
                    if (prevlen != result.length) prevdash = false;
                }
                if (i == maxlen) break;
            }

            if (prevdash)
                return result.substring(0, result.length - 1);
            else
                return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No, no, no. You are all so very wrong. Except for the diacritics-fu stuff, you're getting there, but what about Asian characters (shame on Ruby developers for not considering their [nihonjin](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nihonjin) brethren).

Firefox and Safari both display non-ASCII characters in the [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator), and frankly they look great. It is nice to support links like '[http://somewhere.com/news/read/お前たちはアホじゃないかい](http://somewhere.com/news/read/%E3%81%8A%E5%89%8D%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A1%E3%81%AF%E3%82%A2%E3%83%9B%E3%81%98%E3%82%83%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%8B%E3%81%84)'.

So here's some PHP code that'll do it, but I just wrote it and haven't stress tested it.

```
<?php
    function slug($str)
    {
        $args = func_get_args();
        array_filter($args);  //remove blanks
        $slug = mb_strtolower(implode('-', $args));

        $real_slug = '';
        $hyphen = '';
        foreach(SU::mb_str_split($slug) as $c)
        {
            if (strlen($c) > 1 && mb_strlen($c)===1)
            {
                $real_slug .= $hyphen . $c;
                $hyphen = '';
            }
            else
            {
                switch($c)
                {
                    case '&':
                        $hyphen = $real_slug ? '-and-' : '';
                        break;
                    case 'a':
                    case 'b':
                    case 'c':
                    case 'd':
                    case 'e':
                    case 'f':
                    case 'g':
                    case 'h':
                    case 'i':
                    case 'j':
                    case 'k':
                    case 'l':
                    case 'm':
                    case 'n':
                    case 'o':
                    case 'p':
                    case 'q':
                    case 'r':
                    case 's':
                    case 't':
                    case 'u':
                    case 'v':
                    case 'w':
                    case 'x':
                    case 'y':
                    case 'z':

                    case 'A':
                    case 'B':
                    case 'C':
                    case 'D':
                    case 'E':
                    case 'F':
                    case 'G':
                    case 'H':
                    case 'I':
                    case 'J':
                    case 'K':
                    case 'L':
                    case 'M':
                    case 'N':
                    case 'O':
                    case 'P':
                    case 'Q':
                    case 'R':
                    case 'S':
                    case 'T':
                    case 'U':
                    case 'V':
                    case 'W':
                    case 'X':
                    case 'Y':
                    case 'Z':

                    case '0':
                    case '1':
                    case '2':
                    case '3':
                    case '4':
                    case '5':
                    case '6':
                    case '7':
                    case '8':
                    case '9':
                        $real_slug .= $hyphen . $c;
                        $hyphen = '';
                        break;

                    default:
                       $hyphen = $hyphen ? $hyphen : ($real_slug ? '-' : '');
                }
            }
        }
        return $real_slug;
    }
```

Example:

```
$str = "~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]\{}|;':\",./<>?\n\r\t\x07\x00\x04 コリン ~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]\{}|;':\",./<>?\n\r\t\x07\x00\x04 トーマス ~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]\{}|;':\",./<>?\n\r\t\x07\x00\x04 アーノルド ~!@#$%^&*()_+-=[]\{}|;':\",./<>?\n\r\t\x07\x00\x04";
echo slug($str);
```

Outputs:
    コリン-and-トーマス-and-アーノルド

The '-and-' is because &'s get changed to '-and-'.

Comment: I really don't know what to say about this piece of information.

Comment: That's a really good example of when NOT to use a switch case statement.

Answer (score -1):

Rewrite of Jeff's code to be more concise

```
    public static string RemapInternationalCharToAscii(char c)
    {
        var s = c.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();

        var mappings = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "a", "àåáâäãåą" },
            { "c", "çćčĉ" },
            { "d", "đ" },
            { "e", "èéêëę" },
            { "g", "ğĝ" },
            { "h", "ĥ" },
            { "i", "ìíîïı" },
            { "j", "ĵ" },
            { "l", "ł" },
            { "n", "ñń" },
            { "o", "òóôõöøőð" },
            { "r", "ř" },
            { "s", "śşšŝ" },
            { "ss", "ß" },
            { "th", "Þ" },
            { "u", "ùúûüŭů" },
            { "y", "ýÿ" },
            { "z", "żźž" }
        };

        foreach(var mapping in mappings)
        {
            if (mapping.Value.Contains(s))
                return mapping.Key;
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: I don't really see the pint of a dictionary if you have to scann it entirely.. why not just a list? if that list of structured data (i see you use dictionary like a tuple). if the list is also a constant, why not define it as follow outside of the method? IMHO in such scenario is much more efficent a constant dictionary as yours but with key and value switched : 'à'-> 'a' , ... , 'ą'->'a', ..., 'ç' -> 'c', ... ,'ž' -> 'z'