# c# Convert string into URL friendly

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I generate a Friendly URL in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37809/how-do-i-generate-a-friendly-url-in-c)

By URL friendly I mean turning:

> Convert string to DateTime in c#

into

> convert-string-to-datetime-in-c

Thank's for any help!