# How can I create a SEO friendly dash-delimited url from a string?

Tags: language-agnostic, string, seo, slug

Take a string such as:

> In C#: How do I add "Quotes" around string in a comma delimited list of strings?

and convert it to:

> in-c-how-do-i-add-quotes-around-string-in-a-comma-delimited-list-of-strings

Requirements:

- Separate each word by a dash and remove all punctuation (taking into account not all words are separated by spaces.)
- Function takes in a max length, and gets all tokens below that max length. Example: `ToSeoFriendly("hello world hello world", 14)` returns `"hello-world"`
- All words are converted to lower case.

On a separate note, should there be a minimum length?

Comment: here's some info on url length: http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html

Comment: Maybe replacing some special characters with their "english pronunciation", e.g. "#" => "sharp", would allow to make better urls and differentiate C from C# (which is good, right ;) ?) ?

Comment: yea definitely, except # isn't sharp, thats a different symbol ;p

Comment: Right... But I think you got my point ;)...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is my solution in C#

```
private string ToSeoFriendly(string title, int maxLength) {
    var match = Regex.Match(title.ToLower(), "[\\w]+");
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
    bool maxLengthHit = false;
    while (match.Success && !maxLengthHit) {
        if (result.Length + match.Value.Length <= maxLength) {
            result.Append(match.Value + "-");
        } else {
            maxLengthHit = true;
            // Handle a situation where there is only one word and it is greater than the max length.
            if (result.Length == 0) result.Append(match.Value.Substring(0, maxLength));
        }
        match = match.NextMatch();
    }
    // Remove trailing '-'
    if (result[result.Length - 1] == '-') result.Remove(result.Length - 1, 1);
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I would follow these steps:

1. convert string to lower case
2. replace unwanted characters by hyphens
3. <del>replace multiple hyphens by one hyphen</del> *(not necessary as the `preg_replace()` function call already prevents multiple hyphens)*
4. remove hypens at the begin and end if necessary
5. trim if needed from the last hyphen before position x to the end

So, all together in a function (PHP):

```
function generateUrlSlug($string, $maxlen=0)
{
    $string = trim(preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/', '-', strtolower($string)), '-');
    if ($maxlen && strlen($string) > $maxlen) {
        $string = substr($string, 0, $maxlen);
        $pos = strrpos($string, '-');
        if ($pos > 0) {
            $string = substr($string, 0, $pos);
        }
    }
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: I like this solution. I was trying to do this by matching all non alphanumerics and splitting them joining on - I kept trying to match only if they weren't the start or end of the string, but never got it working. In the end i settled on matching the words, and appending.

Comment: What if the first word is longer than the maximum length ?

Comment: i returned a substring in that situation

Answer (score 4):

C#

```
public string toFriendly(string subject)
{
    subject = subject.Trim().ToLower();
    subject = Regex.Replace(subject, @"\s+", "-");
    subject = Regex.Replace(subject, @"[^A-Za-z0-9_-]", "");
    return subject;
}
```

Comment: i think this has a few issues because what about this situation:

(string)someObject fails.

becomes: stringsomeobject-fails

Comment: that did occur to me, but frankly I'm not sure how I'd want to handle it. In the past I've gone with nuking everything between and including the parens, but I suspect it's implementation specific. Whatever you want though, it's trivial to add to the above template.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution for php:

```
function make_uri($input, $max_length) {
  if (function_exists('iconv')) {  
    $input = @iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $input);  
  }

  $lower = strtolower($input);


  $without_special = preg_replace_all('/[^a-z0-9 ]/', '', $input);
  $tokens = preg_split('/ +/', $without_special);

  $result = '';

  for ($tokens as $token) {
    if (strlen($result.'-'.$token) > $max_length+1) {
      break;
    }

    $result .= '-'.$token;       
  }

  return substr($result, 1);
}
```

usage:

```
echo make_uri('In C#: How do I add "Quotes" around string in a ...', 500);
```

Unless you need the uris to be typable, they don't need to be small.  But you should specify a maximum so that the urls work well with proxies etc.

Answer (score 2):

A better version:

```
function Slugify($string)
{
    return strtolower(trim(preg_replace(array('~[^0-9a-z]~i', '~-+~'), '-', $string), '-'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution in Perl:

```
my $input = 'In C#: How do I add "Quotes" around string in a comma delimited list of strings?';

my $length = 20;
$input =~ s/[^a-z0-9]+/-/gi;
$input =~ s/^(.{1,$length}).*/\L$1/;

print "$input\n";
```

done.

Answer (score 1):

Solution in shell:

```
echo 'In C#: How do I add "Quotes" around string in a comma delimited list of strings?' | \
    tr A-Z a-z | \
    sed 's/[^a-z0-9]\+/-/g;s/^\(.\{1,20\}\).*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is close to how Stack Overflow generates slugs:

```
public static string GenerateSlug(string title)
{
    string slug = title.ToLower();
    if (slug.Length > 81)
      slug = slug.Substring(0, 81);
    slug = Regex.Replace(slug, @"[^a-z0-9\-_\./\\ ]+", "");
    slug = Regex.Replace(slug, @"[^a-z0-9]+", "-");

    if (slug[slug.Length - 1] == '-')
      slug = slug.Remove(slug.Length - 1, 1);
    return slug;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To do this we need to:

1. Normalize the text
2. Remove all diacritics
3. Replace international character
4. Be able to shorten text to match SEO thresholds

I wanted a function to generate the entire string and also to have an input for a possible max length, this was the result.

```
public static class StringHelper
{
/// <summary>
/// Creates a URL And SEO friendly slug
/// </summary>
/// <param name="text">Text to slugify</param>
/// <param name="maxLength">Max length of slug</param>
/// <returns>URL and SEO friendly string</returns>
public static string UrlFriendly(string text, int maxLength = 0)
{
    // Return empty value if text is null
    if (text == null) return "";

    var normalizedString = text
        // Make lowercase
        .ToLowerInvariant()
        // Normalize the text
        .Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);

    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    var stringLength = normalizedString.Length;
    var prevdash = false;
    var trueLength = 0;

    char c;

    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
    {
        c = normalizedString[i];

        switch (CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c))
        {
            // Check if the character is a letter or a digit if the character is a
            // international character remap it to an ascii valid character
            case UnicodeCategory.LowercaseLetter:
            case UnicodeCategory.UppercaseLetter:
            case UnicodeCategory.DecimalDigitNumber:
                if (c < 128)
                    stringBuilder.Append(c);
                else
                    stringBuilder.Append(ConstHelper.RemapInternationalCharToAscii(c));

                prevdash = false;
                trueLength = stringBuilder.Length;
                break;

            // Check if the character is to be replaced by a hyphen but only if the last character wasn't
            case UnicodeCategory.SpaceSeparator:
            case UnicodeCategory.ConnectorPunctuation:
            case UnicodeCategory.DashPunctuation:
            case UnicodeCategory.OtherPunctuation:
            case UnicodeCategory.MathSymbol:
                if (!prevdash)
                {
                    stringBuilder.Append('-');
                    prevdash = true;
                    trueLength = stringBuilder.Length;
                }
                break;
        }

        // If we are at max length, stop parsing
        if (maxLength > 0 && trueLength >= maxLength)
            break;
    }

    // Trim excess hyphens
    var result = stringBuilder.ToString().Trim('-');

    // Remove any excess character to meet maxlength criteria
    return maxLength <= 0 || result.Length <= maxLength ? result : result.Substring(0, maxLength);
}
}
```

This helper is used for remapping some international characters to a readable one instead.

```
public static class ConstHelper
{
/// <summary>
/// Remaps international characters to ascii compatible ones
/// based of: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/non-us-ascii-characters-dropped-from-full-profile-url/7696#7696
/// </summary>
/// <param name="c">Charcter to remap</param>
/// <returns>Remapped character</returns>
public static string RemapInternationalCharToAscii(char c)
{
    string s = c.ToString().ToLowerInvariant();
    if ("àåáâäãåą".Contains(s))
    {
        return "a";
    }
    else if ("èéêëę".Contains(s))
    {
        return "e";
    }
    else if ("ìíîïı".Contains(s))
    {
        return "i";
    }
    else if ("òóôõöøőð".Contains(s))
    {
        return "o";
    }
    else if ("ùúûüŭů".Contains(s))
    {
        return "u";
    }
    else if ("çćčĉ".Contains(s))
    {
        return "c";
    }
    else if ("żźž".Contains(s))
    {
        return "z";
    }
    else if ("śşšŝ".Contains(s))
    {
        return "s";
    }
    else if ("ñń".Contains(s))
    {
        return "n";
    }
    else if ("ýÿ".Contains(s))
    {
        return "y";
    }
    else if ("ğĝ".Contains(s))
    {
        return "g";
    }
    else if (c == 'ř')
    {
        return "r";
    }
    else if (c == 'ł')
    {
        return "l";
    }
    else if (c == 'đ')
    {
        return "d";
    }
    else if (c == 'ß')
    {
        return "ss";
    }
    else if (c == 'þ')
    {
        return "th";
    }
    else if (c == 'ĥ')
    {
        return "h";
    }
    else if (c == 'ĵ')
    {
        return "j";
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
}
```

To the function would work something like this

```
const string text = "ICH MUß EINIGE CRÈME BRÛLÉE HABEN";
Console.WriteLine(StringHelper.URLFriendly(text));
// Output: 
// ich-muss-einige-creme-brulee-haben
```

This question has already been answered many time [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-does-stack-overflow-generate-its-seo-friendly-urls/25486#25486) but not a single one was optimized. 
you can find the entire sourcecode [here on github](https://github.com/zarxor/url-friendly-slug) with some samples.
More you can read from [Johan Boström's Blog](https://johanbostrom.se/blog/how-to-create-a-url-and-seo-friendly-string-in-csharp-text-to-slug-generator/). More on this is compatible with .NET 4.5+ and .NET Core.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly cleaner way of doing this in PHP at least is:

```
function CleanForUrl($urlPart, $maxLength = null) {
    $url = strtolower(preg_replace(array('/[^a-z0-9\- ]/i', '/[ \-]+/'), array('', '-'), trim($urlPart)));
    if ($maxLength) $url = substr($url, 0, $maxLength);
    return $url;
}
```

Might as well do the `trim()` at the start so there is less to process later and the full replacement is done with in the `preg_replace()`.

Thxs to cg for coming up with most of this: [What is the best way to clean a string for placement in a URL, like the question name on SO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539920/what-is-the-best-way-to-clean-a-string-for-placement-in-a-url-like-the-question/540491#540491)

Answer (score 0):

*Another season, another reason, for choosing Ruby* :)

```
def seo_friendly(str)
  str.strip.downcase.gsub /\W+/, '-'
end
```

That's all.

Comment: That's for Rails, not for vanilla Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

In python, (if django is installed, even if you are using another framework.)

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify
slugify("In C#: How do I add "Quotes" around string in a comma delimited list of strings?")
```