# How can I create a SEO friendly dash-delimited url from a string in PYTHON?

Tags: python, url

Basically, my question is the same as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465659/how-can-i-create-a-seo-friendly-dash-delimited-url-from-a-string) but in Python (and GAE), not C#.

Requirements:

- Separate each word by a dash and remove all punctuation (taking into account not all words are separated by spaces.)
- Function takes in a max length, and gets all tokens below that max length. Example: ToSeoFriendly("hello world hello world", 14) returns "hello-world"
- All words are converted to lower case.

Comment: Note: You don't say `SEO Friendly` instead say `Search engine Friendly`
Since SEO is Search-Engine-Optimization

Comment: That's logical, but now you've just doubled the term's letter count.

Comment: How about "SE friendly"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def ToSeoFriendly(s, maxlen):
    '''Join with dashes, eliminate punction, clip to maxlen, lowercase.

        >>> ToSeoFriendly("The quick. brown4 fox jumped", 14)
        'the-quick-brow'

    '''
    t = '-'.join(s.split())                                # join words with dashes
    u = ''.join([c for c in t if c.isalnum() or c=='-'])   # remove punctation   
    return u[:maxlen].rstrip('-').lower()                  # clip to maxlen

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    print doctest.testmod()
```

Answer (score 3):

The term you're searching for is '[slugify](http://www.google.com.au/search?gcx=c&ix=c1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=slugify)'.

Answer (score 3):

As alternative (and probably more tested version) I'm suggesting you use the (minimal modified) slugify code from Django:

```
import unicodedata
import re

def slugify(value):
    """
    Normalizes string, converts to lowercase, removes non-alpha characters,
    and converts spaces to hyphens.
    """
    value = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', value).encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('ascii')
    value = re.sub('[^\w\s-]', '', value).strip().lower()
    return re.sub('[-\s]+', '-', value)
```

See: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/text.py#L435