# How to concatenate safely uri path segments?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have a code which looks like this

```cs
public async Task DeleteUser(string userId)
{
   await httpClient.DeleteAsync($"/v1/api/users/{userId}");
}
```

The problem is that a malicious entry could delete something else than the expected user.
For example, if one user has many blog posts, a malicious entry could be `userId="/v1/api/users/12394/posts/4"`, which would delete a blog post rather than removing the user.

Now, it seems that the `Uri` class has 3 differents escape methods. `Uri.EscapeUriString`, `Uri.EscapeString` and `Uri.EscapeDataString`.
However, the documentation around those and their differences either do not exist, or are really impossible to understand, requiring to read [3 RFCs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapeuristring) to understand the purpose.

I remember I even saw additional methods (I think in a class called `WebUtility`) somewhere which also escape things in URL.

So what is the correct way of escaping a path segment?

EDIT:

I forgot `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`.

Comment: Do you have a chance to expect an integer value instead of a string?

Comment: This is just an example, in this specific case yes, but in other case no.

Comment: You may want to consider [regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342775/what-is-the-best-way-to-clean-a-url-with-a-title-in-it) to do the heavy lifting of cleaning URIs. You may also want to check to see if the URI is [well formed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.iswellformedoriginalstring?view=net-5.0) and [prevent escaping on the URI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?view=net-5.0#security-considerations)

Comment: In this specific example, the malicious query is well formed. If it was not well formed, this would not be a problem since HttpClient would catch it.

Regular expressions for something that is so ubiquitous seems overkill to me...

Comment: [`Uri.EscapeDataString`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4396598/4137916).

Comment: It seems `EscapeDataString` is closer to what I want indeed. That said, the answer you link seems to be using it for the query string, not for path segment.

Comment: True, but the set of reserved characters is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Some after some search and answers in comments I found those links explaining things:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47877559/19803

[What's the difference between EscapeUriString and EscapeDataString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396598/whats-the-difference-between-escapeuristring-and-escapedatastring)

The short answer is `EscapeDataString`.