# ASP.NET MVC - how to replace %20 with dash?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does StackOverflow generate its SEO-friendly URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-does-stackoverflow-generate-its-seo-friendly-urls)

I made a simple form that contains the NAME and some other fields.
When user submits form, the following route will be called:
~/Profile/NAME

If user entered John Smith as NAME, my URL will be:
~/Profile/John%Smith
And I want it to be:
~/Profile/John-Smith

The application will display user details and again the same form at the top of the page. 
NAME value will be passed to the form via ViewData.
I want to populate text box with *John Smith*, not *John-Smith*.

How can I do that? I ran out of ideas.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I have found solution here: http://goneale.com/2008/12/19/lowercase-route-urls-in-aspnet-mvc/. 
It needs a little modification, but basically this is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps any, I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-do-you-include-a-webpage-title-as-part-of-a-webpage-url/25486#25486) from Jeff Atwood as well as the link you garnered above to make it happen.

Comment: Thank you! Very quality answer.

Answer (score 1):

[HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx), look into [UrlDecode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urldecode.aspx) / [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx)

**Edit**

Use jQuery. Pseudo:

```
<input type="text" value="name" />
<input type="submit" id="submit" />
```

The jQuery

```
$('submit').click(function() {
 $('name').val($('name').val().replace(' ', '-'));
});
```

It can look something like that, and when you want to display it, you just replace - with space, but remember, there are names that contain - and should not be replaced.

Comment: `UrlEncode` will not replace `%20` with dash or the other way round with `UrlDecode`.

Comment: Correct. And I mentioned that I need it for ASP.NET MVC, not classic web forms.

Comment: Ah I miss read, i thought that he wanted to encode the url and the decode it to get "John Smith" out of "John%Smith".

Comment: @OP, you can still use HttpUtility even if it's not Web Forms.

Comment: Can I solve the problem by using Route class? This solution will not work if the user switched off java script.

Comment: I don't think you can use Routing for this.. You can probably use some special routing and replace it before it's passed down to the controller.. But more than that, I don't know you have to try. Just wondering, why do you want to have a "javascript turned off"-solution? Does people still turn js off?...