# Replace chars in routeurl's?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, friendly-url, slug

I'm trying to add a "fullname" in the route in my url, and I wonder which chars I should replace? Should I use _ instead of space? and what other chars might "need" replacing?

Mostly gonna use swedish names, but some might have some strange letters, not icelandic ones though :)

/M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [how stackoverflow includes titles in the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-do-you-include-a-webpage-title-as-part-of-a-webpage-url/25486#25486). It could help.

Answer (score 1):

For SEO purposes...

Google has confirmed that the point (.), the comma (,) and the hyphen (-) are valid word separators in URL’s.

You're also better off removing any special characters from the names completely.  For a complete description see this article...

http://www.internetofficer.com/seo/google-word-separator/