# String compare : Comparing 'zürich' and 'zurich' results in -1

Tags: string, compare

I'm trying to do a string compare for 'zürich' and 'zurich'
Something like this:

```
int compareResult = String.Compare(zürich, zurich);
```

So what happens is that it returns `-1`, which causes a problem as I'm using compareResult for an if-else later.

Can someone point me to the right direction on why does this happen. Do I need to clean this first before comparing "zürich" or is it something else?

Comment: What language are you using? This is of great significance. Apart from that, are "zürich" and "zurich" variables or strings?

Comment: If it's Java what you're using, take a look at java.text.Collator: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html

Comment: sorry guys i'm using c#

Comment: @bash.d
both are variable and then compared.i.e.
string a = city:
string b = state;
and then compared.

Comment: Internally C# uses Unicode-strings, so "zürich" and "zurich" are different. Maybe you should try to have a little routine to replace umlaut-characters before comparing them...

Answer (score 0):

you use the method just fine, but the strings are actually different.

so, in order to make this comparison in your way, you need:

1. decide if this you want every comparison that uses ü and other "special" latin characters to look at them as they were the simple characters. 
   **i.e. in every time you see ü, it will treat it as a "u"**
2. if so, you need to do  **pre-processing**  of both the strings, and replace all special chars with regular ones. 
   there is another thread about it here: 
   [How can I remove accents on a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3769457/how-can-i-remove-accents-on-a-string)

hope it helped.