# ASP.NET MVC 400 Bad Request with URL restricted characters such as %

Tags: url, asp.net-mvc-3, bad-request

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC 3 blog application using VS10 and its asp.net development server, and today I encountered the "HTTP Error 400 - Bad Request" error when I request on a blog post with a slug that has these chars "doesn%25e2%2580%2599t" in it.

I thought the "%" char is allowed in the URL, for example, on StackOverflow you have https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23 and this link shows you all questions tagged with c#.  So what is the difference for my URL and how do you fix it?  Could anyone explain.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may checkout the [following blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx) in which Scott Hanselman explains how you could *enable* special characters in urls. Don't get too fancy though, it's still pretty limited. You might also checkout the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-do-you-include-a-webpage-title-as-part-of-a-webpage-url/25486#25486) to see how this is implemented on SO (the post is pretty old and things might have changed since but still good source for information).

Comment: Thank you Darin for pointing out to me those info, they are very helpful.  I have upvoted you and marked you as answer.