# Text URL for website in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I am developing my blog website in asp.net. 
I am saving my blog post in sql server 2005 database.

I am storing like this in my database

- PostId INT IDENTITY
- PostText
- PostAuthor
- PostedDate
- IsActive

So, at the code side when user is clicking on the tag/link. It is comming like this 
http://www.mysite.com/readBlog.aspx?Id=2

On the readBlog.aspx page I am reading the URL and fetching the data from the database. But this is something unprofessional. I want URL like this

[Scott Gu post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2011/03/15/visual-studio-2010-sp1.aspx)

How can I achieve it in simpler manner?

**EDIT**

It is just when I want to share the URL of my website I can do like this

http://www.mysite.com/readBlog/How-to-install-visual-studio

Comment: @Alex, ok sorry! No worries :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look onto [`ASP.NET Routing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).

Just register a route in your `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("readblog",
        "readblog/{id}/{title}",
        "~/readBlog.aspx");
}
```

and then it could be accessed by using e.g.:

```
var path = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(
    null, 
    "readblog", 
    new RouteValueDictionary {{ "id", blogId }, { "title", URLFriendly(title) }}
).VirtualPath;
```

where `URLFriendly` produces URL-friendly version of a title (a very nice example of it could be taken from Jeff Atwood's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-do-you-include-a-webpage-title-as-part-of-a-webpage-url/25486#25486)). This could produce URLs like:

`/readBlog/2/how-to-install-visual-studio` or
`/readBlog/3/something-else`.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to look into URL Rewriting.

Maybe take a look at a [Scott Gu Post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) on the subject.