# Illegal character % in ASP MVC route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, url, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I need to match this route in my ASP MVC application:

```
http://localhost/<itemName>/details
```

When the item name has illegal characters, for example the % symbol, the following URL will blow up:

```
(1) http://localhost/item%25Name/Details
```

In this case the correct URL would be:

```
(2) http://localhost/Details/?item=item%25Name
```

Is it possible to define routes in `RegisterRoutes` to match normal routes to (1), and routes with the % symbol in the item name, to (2)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I would recommend you:

1. For everything that is part of the query string you don't have to worry. It's not necessary to do any special routing.
2. For everything that goes into the path part of the url you could filter dangerous characters. [Here's how this is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-do-you-include-a-webpage-title-as-part-of-a-webpage-url/25486#25486) on StackOverflow with question titles in the url for example.

Comment: Upss, not valid for, me. I need an exact copy of the item name in the server side. The item name is really a file path to search in a Version Control System, so as you can imagine, this must be exact.

Comment: @Daniel Peñalba, then I am afraid you will have very hard time using those characters as part of the URL path. In this case probably the query string is the way to go. Avoid using url tokens for variables that can contain such characters as IIS won't give you peace.

Comment: The original question, is any way to define routes that match normal routes to (1) and routes with illegal symbols to (2)?

Comment: @Daniel Peñalba, no, as if there are illegal symbols IIS will probably drop the request much before it ever had a chance to hit the ASP.NET engine which is running your application.