# Asp.Net Routing - Replace white spaces %20 with dashes from URLs generated

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, seo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does StackOverflow generate its SEO-friendly URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-does-stackoverflow-generate-its-seo-friendly-urls)

I use Asp.net 4 and Routing

I use this Route to create SEO friendly URLs for my website.
`Title` url paramenter is a string example "This is a Title" as result I get the URL in browser with this format `/Content/This%20is%20a%20Title`.

I would rather have the white spaces **%20 replaced** with a more readable dash for example: `/Content/This-is-a-Title`.

Any idea how to do it? Thanks for your help on this

```
        routes.MapPageRoute(
            "View Content",                     // Route name
            "Content/{Title}",                  // Route URL
            "~/Cms/FrontEndCms/Content.aspx"    // Web page to handle route
        );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you redirect to this URL, use the following:

```
Response.Redirect(Page.GetRouteUrl(
    "View Content", 
    new { Title=(yourtitlehere).ToString().Trim().Replace(" ","-") })
);
```

I added `Trim()`. If the title starts or ends with a space the server may think it's a different path and return a `404: Resource not found`.

Comment: hi thanks for your answer but the code should run on routing natively.

Comment: yes when you redirect or you can set url of links with that code

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. Your solution is quick to adopt, but I suppose could have some performance draw back. At the end I'm stripping my urls and storing in the DB, so I use routing to get the clean URL or my links. Anyway many thanks :)

Comment: I am having the same problem and came to this link.. I think it is quite useful to have: http://www.deliveron.com/blog/post/SEO-Friendly-Routes-with-ASPnet-MVC.aspx