# .NET MVC3 Routing URL Rewriting

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-routing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does StackOverflow generate its SEO-friendly URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-does-stackoverflow-generate-its-seo-friendly-urls)

I have an MVC3 site for which I would like to clean up the urls that contain spaces in the names of the products.

Currently, the url displays as: `/products/some%20ugly%20url`

I would like to display: `/products/some-clean-url`

Is it possible with MVC3 routing to rewrite the ugly url to the clean one?

Comment: Can't you just rename your files with - instead of spaces?

Comment: Unfortunately no because it relies on another service that requires the spaces. I suppose I could do the rewrite before the service call though instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **yes this is possible**. Just look up. StackExchange runs on ASP.NET MVC.

Try creating a product **slug**. A slug is a unique string that identifies your item that you want to fetch.

```
/products/fake-blood
/products/spiders-webs
/products/vampire-teeth
```

You can then key off the slug, instead of an ID. Many solutions store the slug in the database.

Comment: Thanks, this is a possible solution. I guess I worded my question poorly, I know that its possible, I was wondering whether it was possible natively through routing.