# clean url with mvc 3, similar to stackoverflow ones

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, encoding

```
 <a href="/NewsDetail/@News.Title/Id">Foo</a>
```

When i click on this, it s being encoded and instead of space I m seeing %20 and so forth.

How can i create cleaner URLs ? just like what stackoverflow has?

Is there a utility for this?

I want something like this?

```
foobar.com/NewsDetail/some-specific-title/1
```

Comment: I guess you mean a slug. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slug+asp.net-mvc

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does StackOverflow generate its SEO-friendly URLs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-does-stackoverflow-generate-its-seo-friendly-urls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how stackoverflow does it:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-does-stackoverflow-generate-its-seo-friendly-urls
```

Comment: that s fine. that s what i have.

Answer (score 0):

Read up on MVC routing for the default system.

And checkout this project AttributeRouting, install with nuget AttributeRouting, then you can put `[GET("NewsDetail/some-malformed-title/1")]` in front of your action and it just works.