# Using a slug in URL & ID to query DB in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url-routing, slug

I am trying to use slugs in an MVC web application but can seem to work out the best way to implement them.

I have found the the recommendation on how to create the URL friendly slug [stackoverflow slug post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-does-stackoverflow-generate-its-seo-friendly-urls/25486#25486)

I still want to be able to query the Db with the ID but don't want this to be in the URL similarly to most stackoverflow URLs, for example

```
http://website/home/list/outdoor-products
```

How can a slug be displayed in the URL while still passing and using an ID to be used to query with?

Comment: What's wrong with saving friendly URL piece in product's database and querying with slug - ".First(p => p.URL == slug)"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doesn't really depends on a technology/framework which you are using, the main thing is you have to have destinctive urls to unambiguously select page content.
If you do have unique titles/slugs for pages, then you may use them as identity for content selection. Otherwise, you need to put some sort of id (it could be int or guid, whatever) into your urls. There isn't anything which will hide your int id behind the slug.
Talking about stakoverflow's urls, you'll find id just before the friendly title. Another option could be put actual id at the end of friendly title (friendly-title-1559063).