# Add string to the requested URL

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, seo

I have a route established like the return a particular blog entry when accessed
It looks like this

```
www.mywebsite.com/100
```

However I want that when returning the page I also add the blog title to the URL
For e.g. user may enter the above url but when he gets the page back the url must look like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/100/My-Blog-Title
```

Just like it happens here on Stakoverflow that:
I enter this URL

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/
```

And after the request is received the URL looks like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-an-unsorted-array
```

How can achieve this in my MVC project? Can anyone please help.

Please also comment over the `SEO` friendliness while suggesting your preffered approach.

Thankyou

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-does-stack-overflow-generate-its-seo-friendly-urls/25486#25486

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a simple redirection. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript for it.

Return the blog title stored in a JavaScript variable somewhere.

```
var blogTitle = "My-Blog-Title"
```

Read the blog title and read this [link](http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/) to change the url without redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the Network tab in the Chrome Developer tools and load up the address (id only) to this question (`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005768/`), you'll see that you get back a an `HTTP 301` response - a permanent redirect to the friendly url (`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21005768/add-string-to-the-requested-url/`).

To respond with this in ASP.NET MVC you would do something like the following:

```
public ActionResult GetThingy(int id)
{
    var title = GetTitle(id);
    return RedirectPermanent(Url.Action("GetThingy", new { id = id, title = title} );
}
```

that would redirect to another action on the controller like:

```
public ActionResult GetThingy(int id, string title)
{
    //do your thing here
}
```