# how to make custom routes in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a URL `http://localhost:3000/features?feature_group=everyone` and i am trying to make the URL `http://localhost:3000/features/for-everyone` how this can be done through routes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does Stack Overflow generate its SEO-friendly URLs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-does-stack-overflow-generate-its-seo-friendly-urls)

Answer (score 2):

You can define desired route as

```
get '/features/:feature_group' => 'features#index'
```

So in action, params[:feature_group] will have 'analytics' in your case

Or you may use collection routes e.g.

```
 resources :features do
   collection do
     get :feature_group
   end
 end
```

So you need a feature_group action in your features controller. To learn about rails routing, ref to http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use your initial `feature` route leading to your index controller and do a nested route within it using a collection for example:

```
 resources :features do
    collection do
      get :feature_group
      get :feature_xxxxx
    end
  end
```

What is cool is that in your controller you can do if params[:feature_group] is nil? or present? or equal to "some words" render your index page with different records or else depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Okay i am able to do it with the help of  [constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints)

```
get 'features' => redirect('/features/for-everyone'), :constraints => lambda{|req| req.params["feature_group"] == "everyone"}

get 'features/for-everyone' => "Features#index"
```

but in the process params["feature_group"] gets lost. So i needed to pass the params in routes using defaults

```
get 'features/for-everyone' => "Featues#index", :defaults => { :feature_group => "everyone" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
get 'features' => redirect('/features/for-everyone?%{params}'), :constraints => lambda{|req| req.params["feature_group"] == "everyone"}
```

or

```
redirect('/features/for-everyone?feature_group=%{feature_group}'), :constraints => lambda{|req| req.params["feature_group"] == "everyone"}
```

I tested both this scenario and its working fine.