# How to create smart urls containing special characters?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have to create urls for my academy courses, and these courses are containing special characters like `+`, `#`, `?`, `_`, `-`, etc.

How I can replace this with some smart characters? And is there any way to do it without encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're asking about URL slugs, in which case have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25486/4302070).

Code included below.

```
/// <summary>
/// Produces optional, URL-friendly version of a title, "like-this-one". 
/// hand-tuned for speed, reflects performance refactoring contributed
/// by John Gietzen (user otac0n) 
/// </summary>
public static string URLFriendly(string title)
{
    if (title == null) return "";

    const int maxlen = 80;
    int len = title.Length;
    bool prevdash = false;
    var sb = new StringBuilder(len);
    char c;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        c = title[i];
        if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= '0' && c <= '9'))
        {
            sb.Append(c);
            prevdash = false;
        }
        else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
        {
            // tricky way to convert to lowercase
            sb.Append((char)(c | 32));
            prevdash = false;
        }
        else if (c == ' ' || c == ',' || c == '.' || c == '/' || 
        c == '\\' || c == '-' || c == '_' || c == '=')
        {
            if (!prevdash && sb.Length > 0)
            {
                sb.Append('-');
                prevdash = true;
            }
        }
        else if ((int)c >= 128)
        {
            int prevlen = sb.Length;
            sb.Append(RemapInternationalCharToAscii(c));
            if (prevlen != sb.Length) prevdash = false;
        }
        if (i == maxlen) break;
    }

    if (prevdash)
        return sb.ToString().Substring(0, sb.Length - 1);
    else
        return sb.ToString();
}
```

You can find `RemapInternationalCharToAscii` [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7435/non-us-ascii-characters-dropped-from-full-profile-url/7696#7696).

You would then do something along these lines:

```
string courseName = "Biology #101 - A Beginner's Guide!";

string urlFriendlyCourseName = URLFriendly(courseName);
//outputs biology-101-a-beginners-guide
```

**Update**

Per your question in the comments, you could include your `CourseID` in the URL and use that to match a DB entry (i.e. match on `12345` in `http://mycourses.com/12345/biology-101-a-beginners-guide/`). You should also store the result of `URLFriendly(courseName)` in a DB column (e.g. `CourseSlug`) so that you can match on `CourseID`, `CourseSlug`, or both.

Comment: For encoding its fine. Now my case is that I want to decode that string from url and then want to send to Database. based on that some data will be returned if title will match in Db. how to handle it?