# Wordpress Blog type Permalink in MVC(Custom URL Routing)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, custom-url

I am facing a issue in my current project where I want to display custom URl for my pages. I have tried lot of techniques but none of them fulfills my requirement.
I want URL like this:

```
http://www.anyDomain.com/What-Is-Your-Name
```

Currently, I am able to set the URL like this:

```
http://www.anyDomain.com/What-Is-Your-Name?Id=1
```

I want to ignore Querystring from URL. So that Controller can identify the request & respond accordingly.

Here, `Id` is used to fetch details from Database. How can I pass the Parameter Value from `View` to `Controller` so It can identify the request without adding it in URL?

My Controller

```
[Route("~/{CategoryName}")]
public ActionResult PropertyDetails(int Id)
{
}
```

RouteConfig

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}",
    defaults:
    new
    {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",

    }
);
```

My View

```
<a href="@Url.Action("PropertyDetails", "Home", new {@Id=item.ID,@CategoryName = Item.Title })">
```

---

I just Noticed, I want URL like StackOverflow is using

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43774917/wordpress-blog-type-permalink-in-mvccustom-url-routing
```

Comment: i think this url surely solve your problem please try this: http://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/generate-seo-friendly-urls-aspnet-mvc/

Comment: See [Multiple levels in MVC custom routing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31958586/181087).

Answer (score 3):

Using attribute routing to include the `id` and a `title`, the controller can look like this

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}/{*slug}")] //Matches GET 43774917/wordpress-blog-type-permalink-in-mvccustom-url-routing
    public ActionResult PropertyDetails(int id, string slug = null) {
        //...code removed for brevity
    }

    //...other actions
}
```

This will match routes similar to what you observed with what StackOverflow is using.

In the view when generating your urls you can take advantage of the models to generate the format you wanted.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("PropertyDetails", "Home", new { @id=item.ID, @slug = item.Title.ToUrlSlug() })">
```

The `ToUrlSlug()` can be an extension method to convert the model Title to your  desired format `word-word-word`

```
public static class UrlSlugExtension {

    public static string ToUrlSlug(this string value) {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) return string.Empty;
        //this can still be improved to remove invalid URL characters
        var tokens = value.Trim().Split(new char[] {  ' ', '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        return string.Join("-", tokens).ToLower();
    }
}
```

Found an answer here on how to generate the slug

[How does Stack Overflow generate its SEO-friendly URLs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-does-stack-overflow-generate-its-seo-friendly-urls)

With that, the custom URL would look something like

```
http://www.yourdomain.com/123456/what-is-your-name
```

for an `item` with an ID of 123456 and a title of "What Is Your Name"