# How can I replace empty spaces with dashes in a URL route value, while maintaining the integrity of existing dashes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

If I have a URL that looks like this:

```
/Person/30/John Doe
```

When I send it in the browser, it of course gets translated to:

```
/Person/30/John%20Doe
```

In order to make the URL easier to read, I wanted to replace the spaces with dashes. Then before the values get read by the database, I swap out the dashes for spaces. I did this and it works great. Except when I have a value that contains a dash already, it breaks. So the name `John Gloria-Gonzales` becomes `John Gloria Gonzales`.

What's the best way to do this without screwing up the existing dashes?

Comment: Your problem with dashes in the name is precisely the reason that HTML entities like `%20` are used instead.  Readability of URLs is not very high up on the scale of importance.

Comment: Dose this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259/how-does-stack-overflow-generate-its-seo-friendly-urls/25537